# Random HTTPS failing requiring server reboot - cert issue? RRAS/Firewall issue?

Tags: ssl, https

I am wondering if I can pick the brain of some experts out there on some incredibly odd and frustrating behavior we are seeing with our HTTPS pages on our site.
Our server is Windows Server 2003 and at totally random times, HTTPS will just stop working on our site. The only solution to fix it is to reboot the server. Nothing else is affected (including HTTP pages - those still work fine). It may happen 5 times one day and then be fine for a couple days but I would guess it averages 15 times a week. I have a 3rd party site monitoring service hit our HTTPS page and notify me if it is down. I am often woken up at 3 am, 4 am, ... to reboot the server and am pulling my hair out trying to find a solution.

There is nothing in the Error/Event logs

When it happens, I can not RDC into it via external IP, but if I RDC into another server on the domain I am then able to RDC into the problem server using local IP. So I guess technically when this happens, it kills our HTTPS pages AND the ability to RDC using external IP

When it has happened I have RDC'ed into it via local IP and done all the steps located here (https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-ssl-related-issues-server-certificate) and nothing seems out of the ordinary

I have also attempted to restart the site in IIS, recycle the app pool, ... and nothing works except for a full server reboot.

One odd thing I did notice is that if I RDC into another server on the domain and go to the site in a browser via IP and use HTTPS, it DOES work (i.e. https://10.176.1.1). I get the typical browser warning saying the certificate doesnt match the site, but if I click the option to proceed, it then does work.

When the problem is happening:
HTTPS access to the site does NOT work via domain name and external IP
HTTPS access to the site DOES work via local IP
All HTTP access to the site DOES work
RDC into the server via external IP does NOT work
RDC into the server via internal IP (from another server on domain) DOES work

After a server reboot, everything listed above works

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? Or a method for me identify what the problem is? Our HTTPS cert is from GD and one option I was thinking of trying was getting a new cert from a different provider and see if that makes a difference. But that just seems like a total shot in the dark.

Other notes... we are working to retire this server and move everything to our latest ones, however we are handcuffed by some software running on it which we are working on upgrading